# Recover Oracle Database until cancel and noresetlogs

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, recovery, rman

I have to recover an Oracle database from a backup with a controlfile. I want to avoid that archivelogs written after the backup are taken for a recovery. I want to a avoid resetlogs.

I have to switch from rman to sqlplus to issue this statement.

```
RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE
```

Is there a way to do this from rman and to avoid resetlogs?

Comment: you want to recover database from RMAN.

Comment: Yes, if possible. I don't want to switch to sqlplus.

Comment: What type of backup do you have consistent(cold) or inconsistent(hot)? If you perform incomplete recovery then you need to reset log.

Comment: @r0tt, As JSapkota already said, what kind of do you have backup  (noarchivelog or archivelog mode backup).

Comment: I can create both hot and cold. In both cases the recovery from controlfile will use new archivelogs if available right?

Comment: @r0tt in the case of a consistent backup just RESTORE, no need to RECOVER, and the database will be in the state it was at the time of the backup — no later logs will be applied.

Comment: How can I only restore? A recover command is forecd right? http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_backup_controlfile_recovery.htm

Comment: Why do you want to avoid reset logs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cancel, you have no way of using noresetlogs. You have create a new incarnation of your database. 
Ps: I don't know what your problem was with switching to sqlplus, but you can execute sql statements (alter database.....) in rman .

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to Oracle Doc: How to RESTORE / RECOVER COLD RMAN backup without OPEN RESETLOGS(Doc ID 1077022.1).